# How to show the live DateTime as a textView (Like a digital watch) in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile-development

I have made two `textView` in an `xml` file where one `textView` shows current date and another shows current time as `text`.

Now, I have used the java `Calendar.getInstance().getTime()` method to get the date & time information. But it is acting as a static view i.e. it is not changing the date & time like a digital clock.

Now I am trying to show the `textViews` to show the current date & time in synchronization with device-system's date & time. That means, suppose now it is `11:59:59 PM` in the night and the date is `7th Sep, 2022`. Just after `1s`, my time `textView` should show the time as `12:00:00 AM` and date should show as `8th Sep, 2022`. And it should continue to change the time after every `1s` like a digital clock. Last of all, there should not be any delay in between system dateTime & app dateTime i.e. perfectly synchronised.

How to do that??

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textDate, textClock;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textDate = findViewById(R.id.textDate);
        textClock = findViewById(R.id.textClock);
        setDateTime();
    }

    private void setDateTime() {
        Date c = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM, yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
        SimpleDateFormat df_clock = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a", Locale.getDefault());
        String formattedDate = df.format(c);
        String formattedClock = df_clock.format(c);

        textDate.setText(formattedDate);
        textClock.setText(formattedClock);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's already a [`TextClock`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextClock) class in Android which you should be able to use. Try replacing your two `TextView`s with these and [set the formats](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextClock#setFormat12Hour(java.lang.CharSequence)) to your patterns.

Comment: Yes it worked @PPartisan. In the TextClock just I have to set the format for time and date only. TY.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a background thread that will ask the UI to update itself every second.

I think something like this (but I don't know how accurate this will be)

```
private void blink() {
      final Handler hander = new Handler();
      new Thread(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
            // off the UI
            try {
               Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // back ot the UI
            hander.post(new Runnable() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                  // notify the UI here
                  blink();
               }
            });
         }
      }).start();
   }
```

Comment: Yes it also works but it is not perfectly synchronised I think. In my emulator I found little lag between device time update and app time update.